# vbscript xmlhttp request authentication. access is denied

Tags: xml, authentication, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, vlc

I'm trying to grab an xmldocument from the VLC web interface. In the past my script has worked as intended however recent versions of VLC have introduced authentication to access the web interface and there is seemingly no way to disable it (or to change the username).

```
            On Error Resume Next
            Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

            xmlDoc.Open "GET","http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml", false, "", "password"
            xmlDoc.send()
```

I know that the user/pass I am providing is correct since I can access the document through my browser. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is there an actual error that you can provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i needed to set the request header with the password in base64 format

```
xmlDoc.Open "GET","http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml", false, "", "password"
xmlDoc.send()
```

Should have been

```
Dim base64pw
base64pw = "OnBhc3N3b3Jk"
xmlDoc.Open "GET","http://localhost:8080/requests/status.xml", false, "", "password"
xmlDoc.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic "& base64pw
xmlDoc.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using xmlhttp. Edit the url's etc. If it seems to work comment out the if / end if to dump info even if seeming to work. It's vbscript but vbscript works in vb6.

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2
```

Also see if these other objects work.

```
C:\Users>reg query hkcr /f xmlhttp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0
End of search: 12 match(es) found.
```

Comment: Also be aware there is a limit on how many times you can call any particular XMLHTTP object before a lockout occurs. If that happens, and it does when debugging code, just change to a different xmlhttp object.

Comment: I know this is super late.  But the issue was I wasn't setting the request header.